# Poison.Encoder how to rename properties in rendered JSON?

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have the Ecto model below.  When I render, I want the JSON to substitute the property name "layers" for "tilemap_layers".

There are many types of 'layers' in my application, so when I made my database schema, I needed to make a uniquely named schema.  However, this JSON will be consumed by a third-party client where it must be named "layers".

What is the recommended way to do this?

The model is here:

```
defmodule MyProject.Tilemap do
  use MyProject.Web, :model

  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [
    :name,
    :tile_width,
    :tile_height,
    :width,
    :height,
    :orientation,
    :tilemap_layers,
    :tilesets
  ]}

  schema "tilemaps" do

    field :name, :string
    field :tile_width, :integer
    field :tile_height, :integer
    field :width, :integer
    field :height, :integer
    field :orientation, :string

    has_many :tilemap_layers, MyProject.TilemapLayer
    has_many :tilesets, MyProject.Tileset

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(tile_width tile_height width height)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  @doc """
  Creates a changeset based on the `model` and `params`.

  If no params are provided, an invalid changeset is returned
  with no validation performed.
  """
  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poison does not provide a way to alias when using `@deriving`

You can either:

specify the implementation yourself with `defimpl` (taken from [the docs](https://github.com/devinus/poison#encoder)):

```
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Person do
  def encode(%{name: name, age: age}, _options) do
    Poison.Encoder.BitString.encode("#{name} (#{age})")
  end
end
```

Rename the field in the schema:

`has_many :layers, MyProject.TilemapLayer`

or use a Phoenix View:

```
defmodule MyProject.TilemapView do
  use MyProject.Web, :view

  def render("index.json", %{tilemaps: timemaps}) do
    render_many(tilemaps, __MODULE__, "tilemap.json")
  end

  def render("tilemap.json", %{tilemap: tilemap}) do
    %{
      name: tilemap.name,
      ...
      layers: render_many(layers, MyProject.TilemapLayerView, "tilemap_layer.json")
    }
  end
end
```

Then create a TilemapLayerView:

```
defmodule MyProject.TilemapLayerView do
  use MyProject.Web, :view

  def render("tilemap_layer.json", %{tilemap_layer: tilemap_layer}) do
    %{
      name: timemap_layer.name
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks again Gazler!  I am trying the foreign_key option since this is what I really want

Comment: Woot!  This worked!  I'd did need to change a small typo.  I changed foreign_key: :tilemap_id

Comment: @JoshPetitt You probably don't need to specify `foreign_key` actually. Could you try it without?

Comment: BTW, this worked for me by changing the foreign_key, so I edited your answer.  If this is wrong please change it back :-)

Comment: Gazler, you are correct once again!  I did not need foreign_key, I've removed it and it is still working as I want

Comment: @JoshPetitt The name is derived from the current module. I have updated my answer to reflect this. Sorry for the confusion.